# Объявление переменных в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Как в mysql объявить переменную, присвоить ей какое нибудь значение и использовать ее в запросе? Нужно именно средствами mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-Defined Variables

SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;

или

SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;

[Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html),

[статья на русском](http://webew.ru/articles/3923.webew)

Comment: а почему нет инициализации?

Comment: происходит при первом присвоении, можно использовать cast, см примеры в доке